# append text at the end of the specific lines

Tags: java, file, append

I'm trying to do this function in java, but it's not Working
I'm trying to add a new String at the end of the specified line in the existing .txt file(in detail where the variable corso has the same value of dati[0]).

The txt file is formatted like:

course identifier1_title of course1_course description1_teacher identifier1
course identifier2_title of course2_course description2_teacher identifier2

My problem is how can i append the new String user at the end of the line?
I mean how can i add user after teacher_identifier?

this is my function:

```
    public void addStudente(String user,String corso) throws IOException{

    FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Marco\\workspace\\ChatRoom\\corsi.txt");
    BufferedReader lettore = new BufferedReader(file);

    FileWriter fileout = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Marco\\workspace\\ChatRoom\\corsi.txt",true);
    BufferedWriter filebuf = new BufferedWriter(fileout);
    PrintWriter printout = new PrintWriter(filebuf);

    String temp;
    String[] dati = null;

    while((temp = lettore.readLine()) != null){

        dati = temp.split("_");
        System.out.println("line length: "+lettore.readLine().length());
        if(dati[0].equals(corso)){
            printout.write("_"+user, lettore.readLine().length(),user.length()+1);

        }

    }

    printout.close();
    file.close();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write the line you read to the output, and then write your user and finally new line.

```
while(...) {
....
printout.write(temp);
if (...) {
 printout.write("_"+user);
}
printout.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is, you use `lettore.readLine()` multiple times inside the loop body. But you should be aware, that this consumes your input stream, by reading the next available line at each call. But you want only read one line per round. This is done inside the `while` predicate. You stored the line in the `temp` variable. Inside the loop body you should only use this variable and don't call `readLine()` any more.

Then you parse the line to decide if this is the one to add the user. But there is no action for the `else` branch. If this is not the line to modify you should print the whole line as is:

```
if(dati[0].equals(corso)){
  // ...
} else {
  printout.println(temp); // Write the unmodified line
}
```

Then if you found the line to modify, why don't you use the `PrintWriter`'s `print()` and `println()` methods?
Something like that should be sufficient:

```
if(dati[0].equals(corso)){
  // Add the user to the line
  printout.print(temp);
  printout.print('_');
  printout.println(user);
} else {
  printout.println(temp); // Write the unmodified line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, i have fixed my code with your suggestions, now the code is working
i use the following code:

```
public void addStudente(String user,String corso) throws IOException{

    FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Marco\\workspace\\ChatRoom\\corsi.txt");
    BufferedReader lettore = new BufferedReader(file);

    FileWriter fileout = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Marco\\workspace\\ChatRoom\\corsi.txt",true);
    BufferedWriter filebuf = new BufferedWriter(fileout);
    PrintWriter printout = new PrintWriter(filebuf);

    String temp;
    String[] dati = null;

    while((temp = lettore.readLine()) != null){

        dati = temp.split("_");
        printout.write(temp);

            if(dati[0].equals(corso)){

                printout.write("_"+user);
            }

        printout.println();

    }

    printout.close();
    file.close();
}
```

The code add the user correctly, but they don't overwrite the text inside the file.
For example before run the code inside there was:

345_title_course_description
456_title1_course1_description1

after run the file is:

345_title_course_description
456_title1_course1_description1
345_title_course_description_user
456_title1_course1_description1

How can i overwrite che existing text inside the file?